# ANTLR Parse tree modification

Tags: parsing, tree, antlr, grammar

I'm using ANTLR4 to create a parse tree for my grammar, what I want to do is modify certain nodes in the tree. This will include removing certain nodes and inserting new ones. The purpose behind this is optimization for the language I am writing. I have yet to find a solution to this problem. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: No, AFAIK, there is no way to do that. What kind of optimizations are you talking about? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278743/build-ast-in-antlr4

Comment: I am looking to modify the tree, more specifically the terminal nodes and their values, for example if I have an expression 2 + 4, I would like to replace that with a node with the value 6. It's not that big of an optimization but it would be nice to have.

Comment: No, there is no way to replace nodes/subtrees in the parse tree. Perhaps later: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/369

Answer (score 8):

While there is currently no *real* support or tools for tree rewriting, it is very possible to do. It's not even that painful.

The `ParseTreeListener` or your `MyBaseListener` can be used with a `ParseTreeWalker` to walk your parse tree.

From here, you can remove nodes with  `ParserRuleContext.removeLastChild()`, however when doing this, you have to watch out for `ParseTreeWalker.walk`:

```
public void walk(ParseTreeListener listener, ParseTree t) {
    if ( t instanceof ErrorNode) {
        listener.visitErrorNode((ErrorNode)t);
        return;
    }
    else if ( t instanceof TerminalNode) {
        listener.visitTerminal((TerminalNode)t);
        return;
    }
    RuleNode r = (RuleNode)t;
    enterRule(listener, r);
    int n = r.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        walk(listener, r.getChild(i));
    }
    exitRule(listener, r);
}
```

You ***must*** replace removed nodes with something if the walker has visited parents of those nodes, I usually pick empty `ParseRuleContext` objects (this is because of the cached value of `n` in the method above). This prevents the `ParseTreeWalker` from throwing a NPE.

When adding nodes, make sure to set the mutable parent on the `ParseRuleContext` to the new parent. Also, because of the cached `n` in the method above, a good strategy is to detect where the changes need to be ***before*** you hit where you want your changes to go in the `walk`, so the `ParseTreeWalker` will walk over them in the same pass (other wise you might need multiple passes...)

Your pseudo code should look like this:

```
public void enterRewriteTarget(@NotNull MyParser.RewriteTargetContext ctx){
    if(shouldRewrite(ctx)){
        ArrayList<ParseTree> nodesReplaced = replaceNodes(ctx);
        addChildTo(ctx, createNewParentFor(nodesReplaced));
    }
}
```

I've used this method to write a transpiler that compiled a synchronous internal language into asynchronous javascript. It was pretty painful.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach would be to write a `ParseTreeVisitor` that converts the tree back to a string. (This can be trivial in some cases, because you are only calling `TerminalNode.getText()` and concatenate in `aggregateResult(..)`.)

You then add the modifications to this visitor so that the resulting string representation contains the modifications you try to achieve.

Then parse the string and you get a parse tree with the desired modifications.

*This is certainly hackish in some ways, since you parse the string twice. On the other hand the solution does not rely on antlr implementation details.*

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for simple transformations. I ended up using a `ParseTreeWalker` and a custom `...BaseListener` where I overwrote the `enter...` methods. Inside this method the `ParserRuleContext.children` is available and can be manipulated.

```
class MyListener extends ...BaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enter...(...Context ctx) {
        super.enter...(ctx);
        ctx.children.add(...);
    }
}

new ParseTreeWalker().walk(new MyListener(), parseTree);
```