# how to modify ANTLR4 ParseTree?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, parse-tree

I want to modify Java `SytaxTree` in a way of prefixing variables with some `prefix` (using ANTLR4)

Example `myVar++` -> `prefix.myVar++`

```
expression
 |-- expression
 |    |-- primary
 |         |-- myVar
 |-- ++

// ->

expression
 |-- expression
 |     |-- expression
 |          |-- primary
 |               |-- prefix
 |     |-- .
 |     |-- myVar
 |-- ++
```

Assuming my function gets `SyntaxTree` and returns modified `SyntaxTree`, I can't use simple `TokenStreamRewriter` as it produces only `String`, doesn't it? Also [Java8 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4) is given and may not be modified.

I need to modify the tree itself (if it is even possible).

My Skeleton is like: (in Scala but it is almost same as Java)

```
class MyVisitor extends Java8BaseVisitor[Unit] {
    // ...
    override def visitPrimary(ctx: Java8Parser.PrimaryContext) = {
        if (isVariable(ctx)) {    // this condition works
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

I struggle with implementation of `// TODO`. I tried using `addChild` and `getParent` but with no success and throwing Nullpointers.

I guess I don't understand construction/modification of `ParseTree` at all as I found no suitable source.

Could you give me a hint or some sources?

According to [github issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/369) and [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487619/antlr-parse-tree-modification) it appears to be unsupported - what other solutions would you recommend? I think about `TokenStreamRewriter` and `getText` and then parsing again (into new `ParseTree`) but this could be very ineffective (I am about to prefix more than once).

Comment: you might also find this link useful:
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/~admin/2012/12/08/Tree+rewriting+in+ANTLR+v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just alter the text of the variable, I'd do this:

There is

1. the [`CommonToken`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonToken.html) class that implements [`IWritableToken`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/WritableToken.html) class
2. or you create your own writable Token class

cast the `IToken` interface to this class and set the token text (e.g. prepend the prefix).

This modifies the parse tree in place.

If you want to add a different token in front of the variable, this doesn't work.

Comment: I see, thanks for help, I hope we can expect tree modification in following versions of ANTLR